# Como puedo almacenar los valores de un Array en una sola variable String en Arduino?

Tags: arduino

hola tengo he estado reciclando código y me surgió una duda, para almacenar una variable en Arduino al leer un una tarjeta de un RFID RC522.

Lo que pasa es que leo un bloque de un sector en especifico y me escribe en el puerto serial el dato, y como es un *Array* no se como guardar en un *String* 
 esa concatenación para posteriormente usarla en otro lado. Se que lo mas común es múltiples *String* a un vector y no a la inversa.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN 49 // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN 53 // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Create MFRC522 instance.

MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;

void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0; // esta es la funcion
//resetFunc();  // la llamo con esto
/**
* Initialize.
*/
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
while (!Serial); // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 card

// using FFFFFFFFFFFFh which is the default at chip delivery from the factory
for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
}

Serial.println(F("Ingrese Tarjeta"));
}

/**
* Main loop.
*/
void loop() {
// Look for new cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
return;

// Select one of the cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
return;

byte sector = 1;
byte blockAddr = 6; //Se especifica que bloque se leera _____------______-----______
byte dataBlock[] = {
0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, // 1, 2, 3, 4,
0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, // 5, 6, 7, 8,
0x08, 0x09, 0xff, 0x0b, // 9, 10, 255, 12,
0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f // 13, 14, 15, 16
};
byte trailerBlock = 7;
MFRC522::StatusCode status;
byte buffer[18];
byte size = sizeof(buffer);

Serial.println(F("Datos actuales en el sector:"));
mfrc522.PICC_DumpMifareClassicSectorToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid), &key, sector);
Serial.println();

// Read data from the block
Serial.print(F("Cargando dato del bloque ")); Serial.print(blockAddr);
Serial.println(F(" ..."));
status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(blockAddr, buffer, &size);
if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Read() failed: "));
Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
}
Serial.print(F("Dato en el bloque ")); Serial.print(blockAddr); Serial.println(F(":"));
dump_byte_array(buffer, 16); 
Serial.println();
Serial.println();

delay(5000);
resetFunc();  
}

/**
* Helper routine to dump a byte array as hex values to Serial.
*/
/*ESTE ES EL ARREGLO QUE MUESTRA LO QUE TENGO ESCRITO EN EL BLOQUE*/
void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
 //Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
 //Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);

Serial.write(buffer[i]);

}

}
```

Comment: Un string en arduino es un arreglo de char https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/

Comment: si pero lo que busco es el inverso de esto...

void dump_byte_array() // este metodo  me arroja char por char y quiero sumarlos todos en un String pero cuando los sumo aun no estan convertidos de Hexadecimal a char. 

no se si me explico